# PHP Array Find Object's Index

Tags: php, object, find, indexing

How would I figure out where a specific item is in an array? For instance I have an array like this:

("itemone", "someitem", "fortay", "soup")

How would I get the index of "someitem"

Thanks,
Christian Stewart

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`array_search()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

> `array_search` — Searches the array for
>   a given value and returns the
>   corresponding key if successful
>
> `mixed array_search ( mixed $needle , array $haystack [, bool $strict ] )`

Example:

```
$key = array_search('someitem', $array);
```

Comment: Thanks. These are all good answers but I'ma go with this one.

Comment: array_search seems very slow.

Answer (score 2):

```
$index = array_search('something', $myarray)
```

Comment: This is not in the PHP standard library

Comment: Thanks. These are all good answers but I'ma go with the most detailed one :D

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `array_keys($array,$search);` to return multiple keys (indices) for given value

Comment: `indices` fwiw ;) ... and actually they're `keys`, since they don't necessarily have to be numbers.

Comment: Thanks. These are all good answers but I'ma go with the most detailed one :D